# Get confidence intervals and exp with broom from nested coxph-models

Tags: r, tidy, cox-regression, survival, broom

Data and libraries:

```
test <- tibble(start=c(1,2,5,2,1,7,3,4,8,8), 
              age=c(2,3,6,7,8,9,9,9,14,17), 
              event=c(1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0), 
              x=c(1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0),
              sex=c(0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1))

library(tidyverse)
library(broom)
library(survival)
```

I want to nest several grouped tibbles and create coxph objects and extract and nest data with tidy and glance (from broom package). In the tidy output I also want the data to be exponentiated and with confidence intervals. This works:

```
coxph_obj <- (coxph(Surv(start,  event) ~ x + sex + age, test)) 
tidy(coxph_obj, exponentiate = TRUE, conf.int = TRUE)
```

However, I dont know how to get `exponentiate = TRUE, conf.int = TRUE` to work in `tidied = map(fit, tidy)` below:

```
test %>%
  nest(data = -sex) %>% 
  mutate(
    fit = map(data, ~ coxph(Surv(start,  event) ~ x + sex + age, data = test)),
    tidied = map(fit, tidy),
    glanced = map(fit, glance)
  )

 unnest(c(tidied, glanced), names_repair = "universal" )
```

Comment: What does using `tidied = map(fit, tidy, exponentiate = TRUE, conf.int = TRUE)` give you in your `mutate`?

Comment: It worked like magic, thanx!

Comment: Glad to hear...you can provide additional arguments this way to get passed on to the mapped function...

Answer (score 0):

Answer provided by Ben in a comment:

"What does using `tidied = map(fit, tidy, exponentiate = TRUE, conf.int = TRUE)` give you in your `mutate`"